# Drop down menus ?(Select Vehicle) HTML

Tags: html

Making a simple drop down is simple, but how would I be able to check what vehicle they selected in order for the next selection to the be type of model.

P.S. if there's templates out there already I'd appreciate it.

Comment: do you want to use php(mysql) javascript html?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. But there is no template available. But its working...

```js
$("#ddown").on("change",function(){
   $("#ddown ~ select").hide();
  if($(this).find(":selected").text()=="Vehicle 1")
  {
    $("#ddown1").show();
  }
  else if($(this).find(":selected").text()=="Vehicle 2")
  {
    $("#ddown2").show();
  }
  else if($(this).find(":selected").text()=="Vehicle 3")
  {
    $("#ddown3").show();
  }

})
```

```css
#ddown1,#ddown2,#ddown3
{
  display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddown">
    <option>Vehicle 1</option>
    <option>Vehicle 2</option>
    <option>Vehicle 3</option>
  </select>

<select id="ddown1">
    <option>Vehicle 1a</option>
    <option>Vehicle 1b</option>
    <option>Vehicle 1c</option>
  </select>

<select id="ddown2">
    <option>Vehicle 2a</option>
    <option>Vehicle 2b</option>
    <option>Vehicle 2c</option>
  </select>

<select id="ddown3">
    <option>Vehicle 3a</option>
    <option>Vehicle 3b</option>
    <option>Vehicle 3c</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

the simple html version is this that will email you what they entered:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Send e-mail to someone@example.com:</h2>

<form action="mailto:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail:<br>
<input type="text" name="mail"><br>
Comment:<br>
<input type="text" name="comment" size="50"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

the php way is to create a table do an insert statement

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);"
$result = mysqli_query($databaseconnection, $sql);
```

then you could view the results using a SELECT query or you could look in the database (phpmyadmin)

Comment: @Haza The purpose of the site is to answer technical question, starting from specific cases to best pratices for a given Stack. It is certainly not telling that guy how to make a vehicle selection. One should have tell him to explain what he did to get to his goal, and orient him into right documentation as his question is basic enough to be a mere javascript example on any tutorial.